# How do you go up one directory in adb shell?

Tags: adb

writing a vb app to do some cross-platform file manipulations, i'm able to shell out to adb and retrieve the file info i want after drilling down multiple directories (in adb shell i do "cd storage" then "cd extsdCard", etc).  Once i'm 4 or 5 levels deep, i simply want to go up one directory...  old dos would be like "cd.." to go up one level - what's the equivalent in adb shell?  cd.. does nothing, and cd takes me to a data directory and then i'm stuck and have to exit shell and start over.  i seriously feel stupid here, because i'm sure it's something simple - so go easy on me, haven't used adb for a looong time...  tia!

Comment: you need to have a space character between the command(`cd`) and parameters (`..`) like this `cd ..`

Answer (score 6):

Do "cd .." the space should be between